# how to add and remove line to Activity in Manifest file using code?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Is it possible to add & remove line to Activity in Manifest file using code?
this is my activity and I need to add it after `android:launchMode="singleTop"`:

```
<activity
    android:name="prescinto.mobile.ui.workOrder.WorkOrderActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:parentActivityName="prescinto.mobile.ui.project.ProjectActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="prescinto.mobile.ui.project.ProjectActivity"/>

</activity>
```

**I want to add this line using code:**

```
android:noHistory = "true"
```

**I want to add like this;**

```
If(IsOnline) {
        //adding that line
    }else{
        //remove that line
        }
```

Comment: You can't, but some attribute(not all) was config-able by code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not doable, but you can start the activity using the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` which will be equivalent to having that line in the manifest. Perform the check when you want to start it using an `Intent` and then just either add this flag or don't.

Does this suit your needs well? Every flag in Manifest more or less has an equivalent that you can add programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the activity flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` programmatically before you launch that activity. here is a working example relevant to your code/activities:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, WorkOrderActivity.class);

if (IsOnline) {
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
}

startActivity(intent);
```